# How to use a custom model class in the qx.ui.table.model.Remote for each item?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I have an app that have 2 tables (both uses remote models, the data in one table don't overlap with the other):

- one with the new jobs
- one with the (current)/stopped/paused jobs

---

Then I have a main viewer that shows info and let you "act" on the current selected job.

---

Currently this works like this:

1. Click on a job in the new jobs table
2. The job object dispatched in the event is sent to the main viewer.

---

I would like to be able to implement a custom Job class that would be instanced for each job that has been loaded. In this way I could do some easy tasks like: `job.pause()` or `job.start(worker.id);`

Answer (score 0):

The remote table model is only capable of pure data and does not support any model like structures. So it would be in your charge to write these model classes and connect them to your unique identifier you use for your job data.